# WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

When running my test case, any my test program try to start firefox, I got Error. I am using robotframework, Selenium2Library and python 2.7.

```
1Login   [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
| FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
```

I have Xwindows on my CentOS server. I installed firefox using `yum`. My firefox was installed in `firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib64/firefox /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz`

What is wrong here? Has anyone had similar experiences? Any references or advice? thx

**EDIT:**

The results, after I run [demos](https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/webdemo#rst-header-running-demo).

```
==============================================================================
Login Tests                                                                   
==============================================================================
Login Tests.Invalid Login :: A test suite containing tests related to inval...
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Invalid Username                                                      | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalid Password                                                      | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Invalid Username And Password                                         | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty Username                                                        | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty Password                                                        | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty Username And Password                                           | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Login Tests.Invalid Login :: A test suite containing tests related... | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n' 

6 critical tests, 0 passed, 6 failed
6 tests total, 0 passed, 6 failed
==============================================================================
Login Tests.Valid Login :: A test suite with a single test for valid login....
==============================================================================
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
Valid Login                                                           | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: Error: no display specified\n'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Login Tests.Valid Login :: A test suite with a single test for val... | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Login Tests                                                           | FAIL |
7 critical tests, 0 passed, 7 failed
7 tests total, 0 passed, 7 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  /root/Downloads/robotframework-selenium2library/demo/output.xml
Log:     /root/Downloads/robotframework-selenium2library/demo/log.html
Report:  /root/Downloads/robotframework-selenium2library/demo/report.html
```

Comment: Please add the code that's throwing the error.

Comment: It works fine on windows. But when I move it to Linux， error occurs. So it should not be code errors. It seems that I miss something when I configure my project on Linux. I am using robotframework and Selenium2Library an python2.7.

Comment: Do you have simple examples which can test whether the whole enviroments works fine? Or any references?

Comment: I have edited the result, after I run [demos](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/tree/master/demo). @Richard

Comment: just in case you have tried everything and it hasn't worked yet and if your firefox version is 47 then downgrade your firefox to version 45. There is some bug in version 47.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selenium needs a display and as Linux does not have one , you need to download a virtual display ([xvnc](http://grox.net/doc/apps/vnc/xvnc.html)/[xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)). Then start the virtual display server and `export` the display.

*Then* it should work

Comment: I have installed `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.13.0-11.el6.centos.x86_64`. Now I export `DISPLAY=:1`. [Demos](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/tree/master/demo) work, but my project still get errors.

Comment: It is solved. The detail is: 1st startup vncserver(e.g. `vncserver :1`). 2nd set `DISPLAY`(e.g. `DISPLAY=:1`). 3rd change directory to my project(e.g. `cd /path/to/my/project`). 4th execute my project(e.g. `pybot ··· ··· ···`). 5th kill vncserver(e.g. `vncserver -kill :1`).

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that you didn't specify a display.  This is a good qay to specify one.

```
$ export  DISPLAY =<<name of server where viewer is configured>>:<<port associated>> 
$ xhost +
```